# Is their any way to make the service runnable when it killed?

Tags: android

Hi all i did research  more than a lot but no one give me the right answer .
I am surprised because my question is so simple ,but didn't found  a single solution.

I found a lots of question like mine but people making their answer round and round ,i am really sick of this now this is my last and final try 
i will appreciate if any of you resolve it 
Let me light up mu Question again in Brief:

i just want to make a simple service which hear the power button (really so simple) ,Now i did that easy thing , i mean i made a service with a broadcast receiver ok (Quite Simple) , and it run well , But!!! whenever i kill the app from background task , then the service stopped automatically , what i want here , that killing the task do not effect my service (how simple is this)

(Note: 1. i already used START_STICKY and Service.START_STICKY
2.Also i did a bad thing that is is called service in onDestroy.
But Still got thumbs down.
)
Please give me  a fine solution 
I will only appreciate after answer
(Because i am really so sick of this )
Here is my Code

MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

}
```

MyService:

```
  public class MyService extends Service {
        private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;
        public MyService() {
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

           IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
             registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

ScreenReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.e("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");

            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

              Log.e("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }}
```

Comment: register receiver in menifest instead of service. It will work definitly.

Comment: i already did that silly things bro

Comment: What's your requirement with the application? Registering receiver in Manifest should work.

Comment: come on man please read my question first

Comment: do you want me to update manifest too?????

Comment: i said it work fine before i kill , that means i already did lots of thing didn't i?

Comment: @FebiMathew i want to print that in log whenever app is killed in background task or not , simple

Comment: You need to print this log Log.e("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");. Right? And it prints when screen off or on happens. Nothing to do with the background task, service task etc.

Comment: this Log.e("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");.is my background task

Comment: @Abhishek would you like to have a service which is "not killable" in any way? i would not....

Comment: yes i want that , (but i will stop that by button click)

Comment: i mean there is (fortunately) no way to create such a service

Comment: but why ? and then what is the difference between in activity and service , we can run activity in background right, and tell how can music player work when it killed

Comment: whats the problem with killing the music player? see: `system settings > application manager > running`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125488/discussion-between-abhishek-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

I am felling so dumb about this , hey i got the answer 
1. Those who think that its not possible are wrong

2. i just try with other device and it works well
3. the issue with my device is i have marshmallow , so if any one have it allow permission from permission manager (works fine ).

Thanks for your time:)